# DRF returns 404 not found on DELETE

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I request a 'DELETE .../id/delete', I get a 404 not found in response by DRF.

I have a successful API with one part of my model, but this error happens on an other part.

I can't see the difference, and I don't know how to debug it.

url.py:

```
url(
        regex=r'^thirdparties/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/',
        view=ThirdPartyDestroyAPIView.as_view(),
        name='thirdparties_delete'
    ),
```

view.py:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ThirdPartyDestroyAPIView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, CurrentUserThirdPartiesMixin, DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = ThirdPartyReadSerializer
    permission_required = 'cashflows.delete_thirdparty'
    raise_exception = True
```

my request:

```
DELETE /api/v1/thirdparties/5/delete/
```

my response:

```
django_1    | 172.18.0.1 - - [18/Nov/2016 16:02:11] "DELETE /api/v1/thirdparties/5/delete/ HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

## Edit 1

It's coming from the get_queryset() method. 
My method is in a mixin:

```
def get_queryset(self):           
        user = self.request.user
        if user:
            if 'category_id' in self.kwargs:
                return ThirdParty.objects.filter(categories__in=self.kwargs['category_id'])
            elif 'sheet_id' in self.kwargs:
                third_parties = ThirdParty.objects.filter(categories__sheet__in=self.kwargs['sheet_id'])
                third_parties = list(set(third_parties))
                return third_parties
            else:
                third_parties = ThirdParty.objects.filter(categories__sheet__in=Sheet.objects.filter(user=user))
                third_parties = list(set(third_parties))
                return third_parties
        else:
            return None
```

And when I change it to:

```
   def get_queryset(self):
        return ThirdParty.objects.all()
```

It works!

Comment: You don't need the `@python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator on a view. Also, is that your entire view? You should have a `get_object` function to get the specific `ThirdParty` to delete. Currently, that view has no idea what to delete.

Comment: @jape I think that the 'pk' argument in the url is intended to be passed to the generic view 'DestroyAPIView', isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but the problem was in the queryset.

This is OK:

```
return ThirdParty.objects.filter(categories__sheet__in=self.kwargs['sheet_id']).distinct()
```

This is NOT OK:

```
third_parties = ThirdParty.objects.filter(categories__sheet__in=self.kwargs['sheet_id'])
return third_parties = list(set(third_parties))
```